# mongodb no role named restore

Tags: database, mongodb, backup

I am trying to create a user with restore privilege so that I can restore locally a database I backed up on a remote server using mongodump (NB the database requires authentification, but my issue is just creating a user for any new database).

I am using mongo3.6.6 locally.

On local machine I have tried to create a user with restore role using the following. Note I am creating a new local database and a new user for the new database.

```
mongo -u Admin -p authenticationDatabase admin

#create a new database that will extract backup to
use backup_data_db

db.createUser[{
  user: "local_user",T
  pwd: "123",
  roles: [
    {role: "read", db: "backup_data_db"},
    {role: "restore", db: "backup_data_db"}]
})
```

Whereupon I get the following error:

```
Error: couldn't add user: No role named restore@backup_data_db
```

I have tried creating a user with multiple role combinations - dbAdmin, readWrite, read, dbOwner, backup, restore. Out of these roles I consistently get 'No role named xxxx@backup_data_db' for only 'backup' and 'restore' roles. It seems there is something special about creating these roles that is different to other roles but I cannot find any documentation on how to create these other than the Mongo docs which I believe I am following.

Note I also tried starting with admin database ie:

```
use admin
```

And repeated the same db.createUser code as above. And got the same error.

What does work - creating a user with root privilege:

```
use admin

db.createUser( {
user: "rootuser",
pwd: "passwd",
roles: ["root", "userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", 
"readWriteAnyDatabase"] } )
```

The [root](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#backup) role has backup and restore privilege and there were no complaints from mongodb when creating this role.

I then could run the following and restore the db OK

```
mongorestore -u rootuser -p passwd --authenticationDatabase admin -d backup_data_db path_to_backup_dir
```

Docs indicate restore is possible without root access, what am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

The error might be because the `restore` role is only available from the `admin` database.

"MongoDB provides the built-in database user and database administration roles on every database. MongoDB provides all other built-in roles only on the admin database."

The `restore` role is in`Backup and Restoration Roles`.

Docs for 3.6 [are here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/built-in-roles/).

For example (this is not tested):

```
db.createUser[{
  user: "local_user",
  pwd: "123",
  roles: [
    {role: "read", db: "backup_data_db"},
    {role: "restore", db: "admin"}]
})
```

Comment: I tried this is not working. And db.createUser[ will be db.createUser(